# Android ListView how to populate with dynamic information retrieved from a google spreadsheet

Tags: android, listview, google-apps-script

I'm working on an android app that takes information from a google spreadsheet and puts in on a list view. However, I'm unable to come up with a solution for this.
Any help would greatly be appreciated.
For spreadsheet integration I use the Google Sheets API.
I know client login is not secure, but this is just a test app for project purposes :)

Here is what my code looks like -

```
package com.bish.test;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.batch.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
    String USERNAME = "cccc@gmail.com";
    String PASSWORD = "xxx";
    ListView list;
    String[] web;
    Integer[] imageId;
    CustomList adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        logIn();

            try {
                refreshData();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ServiceException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter); 

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void logIn()
    {
        final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait ...", "Logging In...", true);
        ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        try {
        service.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        Thread.sleep(2200);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: Check your Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        }).start();
    }

    public void refreshData() throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException
    {



    }

}
```

Comment: Why does this have the google-apps-script tag?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.
This code:

1) Creates a new Spreadsheet

2) Inserts a new Worksheet

3) Inserts some values in the cells

4) Displays the values from the cells

```
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.FeedURLFactory;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.Cell;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.CellEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.CellFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.CustomElementCollection;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;


new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {                                             
    final String SCOPE = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full";
    final String CREDENTIALS = sessionManager.getCredentials().getSelectedAccountName();

    // CREATE A NEW GOOGLE SPREADSHEET WITH THE CORRESPONDING NAME
    SpreadsheetEntry newEntry = new SpreadsheetEntry();
    newEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(Constants.FILE_PREFIX + mFileName));

    URL url = null;
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "CRED: " + CREDENTIALS);
        url = new URL (SCOPE + "?xoauth_requestor_id=" + CREDENTIALS);

        // INSERT THE FILE
        spreadsheetService.insert(url, newEntry);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ServiceException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // I RECEIVE MEDIA NOT SUPPORTED EXCEPTION, BUT THE FILE IS CREATED!!!!
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        // GET ALL THE FILES FROM THE USER'S GOOGLE DRIVE
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = spreadsheetService.getFeed(
                FeedURLFactory.getDefault()
                        .getSpreadsheetsFeedUrl(),
                SpreadsheetFeed.class); 
        // Creating the list of spreasheets in GDrive
        List<com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

            // parsing trough the feed entries
        for (int i = 0; i < spreadsheets.size(); i++) {
            com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry e = (com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry) spreadsheets.get(i);
            // IF WE LOCATE THE FILE BASED ON THE FILENAME
            if( e.getTitle().getPlainText().equals(Constants.FILE_PREFIX + mFileName)) {

                Log.d(TAG, "ENTRY: " + e.getTitle().getPlainText());

                URL worksheetFeedUrl = e.getWorksheetFeedUrl();

                Log.d(TAG, "worksheetFeedUrl: " + worksheetFeedUrl);

                // The first time this feed is used to create the new worksheet
                WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = spreadsheetService.getFeed (worksheetFeedUrl, WorksheetFeed.class);

                Log.d(TAG, "worksheetFeed OK !");

                // Create the second worksheet 
                WorksheetEntry newWorksheet = new WorksheetEntry(15, 5);
                newWorksheet.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("Sheet2"));
                worksheetFeed.insert(newWorksheet);

                // The second time this feed is used to get the worksheets
                worksheetFeed = spreadsheetService.getFeed (worksheetFeedUrl, WorksheetFeed.class);

                // Get the first worksheet and insert the titles
                List <WorksheetEntry> worksheetEntrys = worksheetFeed.getEntries ();
                WorksheetEntry sheet1 = worksheetEntrys.get(0);
                WorksheetEntry sheet2 = worksheetEntrys.get(1);

                URL sheet1CellFeedUrl = sheet1.getCellFeedUrl ();
                CellFeed sheet1CellFeed = spreadsheetService.getFeed (sheet1CellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);

                sheet1CellFeed.insert (new CellEntry (1, 1, getResources().getString(R.string.cell_title_name)));
                sheet1CellFeed.insert (new CellEntry (1, 2, getResources().getString(R.string.cell_title_description)));
                sheet1CellFeed.insert (new CellEntry (3, 2, getResources().getString(R.string.some_string)));                   
                sheet1CellFeed.insert (new CellEntry (13, 2, "=COUNTIF(Sheet1!F2:F,B3)"));
                sheet1CellFeed.insert (new CellEntry (14, 2, "=B9 - TODAY()"));


                // GET THE CONTENT FROM THE CELLS FROM THE SECOND WORKSHEET
                URL sheet2CellFeedUrl = sheet2.getCellFeedUrl ();
                CellFeed sheet2CellFeed = spreadsheetService.getFeed (sheet2CellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);

                List<CellEntry> cellEntryList = sheet2CellFeed.getEntries();
                if(cellEntryList != null && !cellEntryList.isEmpty()) {
                    for (CellEntry cellEntry : cellEntryList) {
                        Cell cell = cellEntry.getCell();
                        Log.d(TAG, "VALUE:" + cell.getValue());
                    }
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                showMessage("Error!");
            }
        });
    }

    return null;
  }
}.execute();
```